# 'for' limit must be a number LUA Error

Tags: lua

So, I'm getting an error that looks like: [ERROR] addons/itemstore/lua/itemstore/lua/itemsure/vgui/container.lua:43 'for' limit must be a number

Here is container.lua

```
local PANEL = {}

AccessorFunc( PANEL, "ContainerID", "ContainerID" )
AccessorFunc( PANEL, "Rows", "Rows" )
AccessorFunc( PANEL, "Columns", "Columns" )

function PANEL:Init()
    self.Items = {}

    table.insert( itemstore.containers.Panels, self )
end

function PANEL:Refresh()
    local container = itemstore.containers.Get( self:GetContainerID() )
    if ( container ) then
        for i = 1, container.Size do
            if ( not self.Items[ i ] ) then
                self.Items[ i ] = self:Add( "ItemStoreSlot" )
            end

            local panel = self.Items[ i ]
            panel:SetItem( container:GetItem( i ) )
            panel:SetContainerID( self:GetContainerID() )
            panel:SetSlot( i )
            panel:InvalidateLayout()
        end

        self:InvalidateLayout()
    end
end

function PANEL:SetContainerID( containerid )
    self.ContainerID = containerid
    self:Refresh()
end

function PANEL:PerformLayout()
    self:SetSpaceX( 1 )
    self:SetSpaceY( 1 )

    local container = itemstore.containers.Get( self:GetContainerID() )
    if ( container ) then
        for i = 1, container.Size do
            local panel = self.Items[ i ]

            if ( panel ) then
                panel:SetSize( unpack( itemstore.config.SlotSize ) )
            end
        end
    end

    self.BaseClass.PerformLayout( self )
end

vgui.Register( "ItemStoreContainer", PANEL, "DIconLayout" )
```

Any solutions anybody can think of? I can't think of anything because to me, it should be working fine?

Comment: It's not that simple, it pulls container.Size from elsewhere, where it's defined as a number.

Comment: Probably, `container.Size` is `nil`

Comment: "where it's defined as a number."  Well, guess it isn't. The code you've brought is excessive, yet not sufficient to say what the program is doing. At the very least, there's a strange line 47: `panel:SetSize( unpack( itemstore.config.SlotSize ) )`, which might be the cause of `Size` not being what you believe it to be.

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty clear. In line 43 you have a for statement that uses container.Size as its limit, which in your case is not a number.

Solution:

use a number as the for limit. If you have to use container.Size and it comes from "outside", find out why it is not a number and what you can do about it. If you cannot make sure its a number then you cannot use it as your for limit.

So put your for loop inside an `if type(container.Size) == "number" then`  statement or similar.